# Redirect with PHP after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

Im doing the following ajax call:

```
$('#save_sale').click(function() {
    var save_sale = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'summary.php',
        data: {save_sale: save_sale},
        success: function(data) { /* Do something here?? */ },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) { }
    });
});
```

Here is my PHP:

```
function createSale()
    {

        if($sale_id = $this->link->inQuery("INSERT INTO nya_forsaljningar(personnr, status, datum) VALUES('".$this->personnr."','".$this->status."','".$this->sale_date."')"))
        {
            $this->link->inQuery("UPDATE services_temp SET active=1 WHERE temppdtls='".$this->personnr."'");
            $this->link->inQuery("UPDATE summary_temp SET active=1 WHERE personnr='".$this->personnr."'");

            header("Location: addcust.php?new_sale=$sale_id");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;   //Kunde inte skapa försäljningen
        }
    }

if(isset($_GET['save_sale']))
{
    $sale_date = date('Y-m-d');         //Datumet då man skapar försäljning
    $personnr = $_SESSION['fil'][3];    //Personnummer på personen, använder detta för att ta fram de olika delarna från tabellerna
    $save_true = $_GET['save_sale'];    //Försäkrar oss av att vi ska hantera en uppläggning av en nyförsäljning

    $new_sale = new newSale($personnr, $sale_date, $save_true, $link, $status='Obehandlad');    //Skapar ett objekt av försäljningen som vi använder för att hantera den nya försäljning, kolla om den är ok, skapar kundbilden, nekar osv.
    if($new_sale->checkService())
    {
        $new_sale->createSale();    //Skapar försäljningen
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Kunde inte skapa försäljningen";
        exit;
    }
}
```

After the sale is created, I want to redirect to addcust.php?new_sale=$sale_id

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: replacing `/* Do something here?? */` with `window.location.href="NEW_URL_HERE.PHP"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You redirect in success:

```
$('#save_sale').click(function() {
    var save_sale = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'summary.php',
        data: {save_sale: save_sale},
        success: function(data) { 
                window.location.href = 'addcust.php?new_sale=' + data
            },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) { }
    });
});
```

Whatever you echo back from the PHP script will be in `data`. So echo `$sale_id` and you'll have your URL.

Comment: What about the php side of variable  `data`

Comment: @Styphon: How do I return the variable data with the correct ID from my class?

Answer (score 10):

You can use JavaScript to redirect in the success handler:

```
success: function(data) { 
    window.location = 'newpage.php';
},
```

It can't be done with a PHP redirect, because that will only redirect the ajax call, not the original browser window.

If you want to use the sale ID in the URL then you will need to output it so it can be accessed:

```
$saleId = $new_sale->id; // or however you get the sale ID
echo json_encode(array('saleId' => $saleId)); // output JSON containing the sale ID
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'summary.php',
    dataType : 'json', // tell jQuery to parse the response JSON
    data: {save_sale: save_sale},
    success: function(data) {
        window.location = 'addcust.php?new_sale=' + encodeURIComponent(data.saleId);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) { }
});
```

Comment: Enough edits to make my browser tab flicker. Proper response nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

on your js page

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'summary.php',
        data: {save_sale: save_sale},
        //success: function(data) { /* Do something here?? */ },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) { }
    }).success(function(data) {
       window.location('addcust.php?new_sale='+data.id)
    });
```

on your php script echo the id

```
$data['id'] = <sale_id>;
echo json_encode($data);exit
```

hope it will work.

Comment: Why would you use two success callback functions?

Comment: it will execute when the ajax call succeed

Answer (score 0):

Return the `$sale_id` from your PHP file if the sale is a success, via `echo` (assuming $new_sale->id would return an id):

```
if($new_sale->checkService())
{
    $new_sale->createSale();    //Skapar försäljningen
    echo $new_sale->id();
}
```

Then retrieve it in your response data and add it to your redirect:

```
success: function (data) {
    window.open("addcust.php?new_sale="+data, "_top");
},
```

This is an example using variables I'm not sure exists, as I don't know how your class works. The logic stays the same, however.

Oh, and fist bump for being swedish.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to do a full redirect, you can use window.location = 'addcust.php?new_sale='+*youridvariable* In the success callback.