# header not being sent but no error message given

Tags: php, jquery

I have made an oop login using php and myqli, I have also used jquery to dynamically check the users input, when the user details are the correct my code logs the user in but the header redirect is not being sent but no error message is given, could it possibly have something to do with i am using json array to return the values back to the user. any help would be mostly appreciated.

**login class**

```
<?php
require "db_config.php";

class login
{


    public function user_exists($username) {
     $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE  username='$username'";    
     //checking if the email is available in db
        $check = Database::getInstance()->getConnection()->query($sql);
    $count_row = $check->num_rows;

    if ($count_row == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }
    public function check_login($username,$password){
        $sql2="SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";    
        //checking if the username is available in the table
    $check = Database::getInstance()->getConnection()->query($sql2);
    $count_row = $check->num_rows;
    if ($count_row == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
        }
  }
     public function is_loggedin()
     {
          if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
          {
             return true;
          }
     }
   public function redirect($url)
   {
       header("Location: $url");
   }
}
?>
```

**login script**

```
<?php
require '../includes/class/login.php';
$login = new login();
$username_error=' ';
$password_error=' ';
$result=' ';

if (isset($_POST['login'])&& $_POST['login'] !== "") 
{ 
    $log = $login->check_login($username,$password);
    if ($log) 
    {
        $login->redirect('home.php');
    } 
    else
    {
        // Registration Failed
        $password_error='Wrong username or password';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] !== "")
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $username = trim($username);
    $user_exists = $login->user_exists($username);
    if ($user_exists) {
        $username_error = '';
    } 
    else {
        $username_error = 'username not found';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] !== "") {

    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = trim($password);
    $password_check = $login->check_login($username,$password);
    if ($password_check) {
        $password_error = '';
    } 
    else {
        $password_error = 'password not found';
    }
}

$return_data=array('username'=> $username_error, 'password'=> $password_error ,'user_session'=>$_SESSION['username']);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
?>
```

**login js code**

```
<?
function validate(username, password, login)
{
    $.post('includes/login.php', {username: username,password: password,login: login,}, 
  function(data){
        $('#username_feedback').text(data.username);
        $('#password_feedback').text(data.password);
        $('#login_feedback').text(data.user_session); },'json');
}

/////////////////////////////////username jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#username').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#username').val() ==='') {
$('#username_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {
validate($('#username').val(),"","");
}
}).blur(function() { 
$('#username_feedback').text('');
validate($('#username').val(),"","");
}).keyup(function(){
validate($('#username').val(),"","");
});

/////////////////////////////////password jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#password').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#password').val() ==='') {
$('#password_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {
validate( $('#username').val(), $('#password').val(),"");
}
}).blur(function() { 
$('#password_feedback').text('');
validate( $('#username').val(), $('#password').val(),"");
}).keyup(function(){
validate( $('#username').val(), $('#password').val(),"");
});
$( "#login" ).click(function() {
validate($('#username').val(),$('#password').val(),$('#login').val());
});
```

Comment: AJAX calls don't automatically process redirects.  (Since, really, the whole point of AJAX is to not have to refresh the page.)  You'll need to redirect from client-side code in response to a successful login.

Comment: Not the solution, but you should definitely add `exit;? after your `header("Location:......");`

Comment: how would I do a redirect on client side

Comment: Hmm... maybe you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807411/redirect-with-php-after-ajax-call

Comment: javascript: `document.location = "newurl";`

Comment: document.location = "newurl"; would this go in my function data where the data is returned back to the user