# PHP Header Redirect Does not Work Within The Ajax Request

Tags: php, redirect, header

After user's filled the input fields and has submitted I use an ajax request to complete the sign up process.In this register.php I'd like to redirect the user to another page after I inserted their info to the database. Everything is fine and nothing is outputted until header() function.  The code below does not redirect and as if nothing happened the callback function of ajax request is processed. I am really stuck here, I don't know what to do.I can try javascript solutions but I'd prefer php solution over that one.
Code:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/profil.php", true, 307); 
exit();
```

Comment: Just one question: why are you using AJAX (which keeps the user on the current page) if your intention is to redirect to another page after the action?

Comment: This is a good question. It may be bizzare but if the user has signed up as student I don't use header() and just update the index page. But if the user has signed up as teacher I want to redirect them to their profile page. This is where it gets complicated, student part works completely fine. But because header() does not work I can't redirect teachers to their profile page.

Comment: I see. If it's important not to reload the page when a student logs in, see [the JS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807411/redirect-with-php-after-ajax-call). Otherwise, if you don't mind the page refreshing, you can have the login form post to index and optionally redirect when you handle the form submission if the user is a teacher.

Comment: Redirect in your Javascript, after you get a successful response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to redirect in the ajax success callback function:

```
success: function(data) { 
   window.location.href = 'http://localhost/profil.php';
}
```

It can't be done with a PHP header redirect, because that will only redirect the ajax call, not the original browser window.